# Mech page size is bigger than reported by squid server

Tags: ruby, mechanize, squid

When I request a page from a url, I get a different size response body than the proxy server that I am going through is logging. For instance, when url='http://www.yahoo.com', the response body size is ~215k while the squid proxy server is logging ~43k.

```
url = 'http://www.yahoo.com'
@webMech = Mechanize.new
@webMech.read_timeout = 60
@webMech.max_history = 10
@webMech.set_proxy(@proxyHost, @proxyHostPort, @userName, @password)    
@webMech.user_agent='Mac Safari'
@webMech.agent.robots = true
puts @webMech.get(url).body.length
```

I was wondering if anybody had any explanation that I could research. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's probably with and without compression.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Does that mean some sites send pages back compressed? I ask because I checked the same url with lynx (same proxy server & settings) and squid reported the size as ~215k.

Comment: Some sites send gzipped response body but only if the request has gzip or deflate in the Accept-Encoding header. Mechanize does send it, lynx may not.

Comment: You are right on the money! @webMech.agent.gzip_enabled = false should me it the same. Not that it's needed, but I was trying to verify some test results. Thanks! (p.s. You should have answered so I could credit you for it; not too late).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 215k is uncompressed and the 43k is gzipped :)